If the High Priest were to be unintentionally killed, what becomes of the man-slaughterer?
I've been studying up on Numbers 35, which concerns manslaughter and murder. If someone is convicted of murder then they must be put to death. However, if it is determined that the death was accidental (or if there is just insufficient testimony) then the man-slaughterer would be exiled to one of the Cities of Refuge. So long as the man-slaughterer remained within the walls of the city, the avenger of blood could not touch him. However, if he was caught outside of the city walls then the avenger of blood could kill him without sin - fulfilling the requirements of the Noahide Covenant (Genesis 9:6).
There is no animal sacrifice or other way given for someone to redeem the man-slaughterer so that he can return home. However, upon the death of the High Priest all of these man-slaughterers are forgiven. They may return home without fear of the avenger of blood. There is no longer a need to cleanse the land with their blood.
Now, what I was curious about was what happens if someone unintentionally kills the High Priest? If put on trial, would that individual be put to death for killing an anointed of the LORD? Would they be exiled to a City of Refuge until the death of the next High Priest?  Or would they immediately be atoned for through the death of the High Priest along with all the other man-slaughterers?

opposite https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47605/759

See Mishnah Makkot 2:7 - one who unintentionally kills the High Priest is exiled to a city of refuge and never leaves.
(There are situations involving multiple people holding the status of high priest simultaneously where it may be possible for the killer to leave - see Maimonides Laws of Murder 7:10 and commentaries there.)

Thanks :) And didn’t know there could be multiple High Priests - I’ll have to dig into that!

@RyanPierceWilliams you’re most welcome. The issue of multiple high priests could come up, for example, if the main high priest is temporarily unavailable to serve (for example for reasons of impurity). A temporary substitute would be needed, but after the original high priest returns to carrying out his duties, the sub still retains many of the characteristics and rules of a high priest.
